# ASUS hardware monitoring

Tags: monitoring

Would like to monitor remote ASUS server hardware status as we do for HP server with HP ProLiant Support Pack and DELL server with OpenManage Server Administrator (OMSA). So is there a similar software for ASUS exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just starting with this myself, but ASUS does have an Enterprise Management Suite (ASWM). It appears to monitor/control the server over the management interface (IPMI). Check out the documentation [here](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/server/ASWM_Enterprise/Manual/E9286_ASWM-Enterprise_ENU.pdf). It appears that there is an agent software piece that can run on the remote machines, but I'm not sure if this is necessary.

You can also access the management interface directly using ASUS's iKVM built-in web server. The management IP interface must be assigned in BIOS (but it can be set for DHCP). Some of the functions require an old version of java, but you should be able to at least monitor server health status and control power states with it.

To set the admin credentials for the management interface, you'll need to fire up an old DOS boot disk with [this](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/server/ASMB4-iKVM/Utility/ASMC4_4_27.zip) utility. Kind of a pain, but should only need to do it once.